# I don't use right side in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I beginning to use Visual Studio Code. Normally I don't use Minimap. I closed the view menu. It's okay. But the right side of the editor is not used. I added an image for more understanding.
[image]

Comment: If you don't see any image : https://preview.ibb.co/nCBxpG/example.png

Comment: This type of question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), not StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Mert, please try to add the image directly into your Question for clarity.  Edit your Question many times if you need to.  Also it would help if you make your question clearer...  Do you use Minimap or Visual Studio?  Which version?  What code are you writing? HTML?

Comment: @Grantly i'm sorry, i used first time stackoverflow. I don't use minimap. It closed. So, i don't see Minimap on our screen. But all languages code page or text page i see a space on right side (i show space area on image)

Comment: Hi @Mert welcome to Stackoverflow.  Thats OK, take your time...But please make your Question more clear...Then it will attract answers.  See here too please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In your user settings (File>Preferences>Settings) set minimap to false

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Yes, i know and i used this. I don't see Minimap. It's true. I show a space area on image. My codes don't continue right side. Yes i use word wrap but bottom line goes down before the end of the line

Comment: Hey @Mert!
Just goto same Settings, and update your `editor.minimap` settings with following 
`editor.minimap.enabled: false`
`editor.minimap.maxColumn: 0`
`editor.minimap.renderCharacters: false`

Comment: @mert:  Please mark this answer if your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"editor.wordWrap"` set to `"wordWrapColumn"` or `"bounded"` it's expected to wrap like this. Set it to `"on"`:

```json
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
```